# How do I access private constants in class attributes in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, attributes, constants

I have an API that I created and currently utilize successfully in C#.  I am trying to create an example of interacting with the API in VB.NET (so that the QA without C# experience can still utilize it for creating automated tests).

In C# I do the following

```
[TestingForm(FormName= "Land Lines", CaseType= _caseType
            , Application= ApplicationNameCodes.WinRDECode, HasActions= true)]
public class LandLines : RDEMainForm
{
    // .. Irrelevant Code .. //
    private const string _caseType = "Land Lines";
}
```

As someone with zero VB.Net experience, I created the following to try and mimic it

```
<TestingForm(Application:=ApplicationNames.WinRDE, FormName:=FORM_NAME, CaseType:=CASE_TYPE, HasActions:=True, IncludeBaseClassActions:=False)>
Public Class Permits
    Inherits TestingBase


#Region "Constants"

    Private Const FORM_NAME As String = "Permits" 'Display name for the test class (in the editor)
    Private Const CASE_TYPE As String = "permits" 'Unique code for this test class, used when reading/saving test plans


#End Region

End Class
```

This gives me a compile time error because it claims that `FORM_NAME` and `CASE_TYPE` is not defined, even though the class has it defined inside.

How can I use the defined constants inside the class in the class attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm actually quite surprised that the C# example compiles (but I checked it indeed does).

In VB.Net that type of access (a private member outside the type even in an attribute) is simply not legal.  Instead you need to make it `Friend` and qualify it's access

```
<TestingForm(Application:=ApplicationNames.WinRDE, FormName:=Permits.FORM_NAME, CaseType:=Permits.CASE_TYPE, HasActions:=True, IncludeBaseClassActions:=False)>
Public Class Permits
    Inherits TestingBase

    Friend Const FORM_NAME As String = "Permits" 'Display name for the test class (in the editor)
    FriendConst CASE_TYPE As String = "permits" 'Unique code for this test class, used when reading/saving test plans

End Class
```